# Distribution of 5 points on a plane where the lines connecting the points are either parallel and/or perpendicular to another

Tags: geometry

The problem is a basic geometry textbook problem (undergraduate level) but has obsessed me for weeks. We are in R^2, with 5 points on the plane. You must find the relative locations of these points so that you achieve that every line connecting two points is either parallel and/or perpendicular to another line. An additional condition is that the points cannot be co-linear and at least one perpendicular relationship exists.
I put an example. You draw a square. Let's say we take coordinates so that A is located at (0,0), B at (1,0), point C at (1,1) and finally point D at (0,1). You add a final fifth point E at (0.5, 1.5). Of all lines connecting the points (10), only 8 of them meet the conditions. Segments AE and BE are not parallel not perpendicular to any other segment (or "line"), but we have 2 sets of parallel lines and BD perpendicular to AC and in the other hand AC and DE are parallel each other and BD is parallel to CE, so **only** 8 lines meeting the criteria. We must find a distribution which has ALL possible lines parallel and perpendicular (so the maximum will be 10 lines meeting criteria) and demonstrate a) if such a distribution exists,  b) and if so, if it is unique or there are a bunch (maybe infinite) of them, and list the properties that they must exhibit.

[image: Five points with 8 relationships, based on a square and its diagonals and parallel to those diagonals]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Angle subtended by a diameter is $90^\circ$.

**Next hint:**

> And again, angle subtended by a diameter is $90^\circ$.

---

One family of infinitely many non-isomorphic configurations:

> Let $AB, CD$ be perpendicular diameters of a circle (IE a square). (which is why the hint appears twice.)
>  Where can we place $E$ in accordance with the hint?

---

I cannot yet prove that this configuration is unique.

If we don't require that a perpendicular exists, then the regular pentagon is another example.

Comment: The square and the fith point at the intersection of the external diagonals is just the example. It is not valid. As for the hexagon, it has 6 points. Also the condition of at least 1 perpendicular condition is mandatory. Come on, the problem is intended for teenagers solving it in 5 minutes with very elemental calculus skills.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1495422)

Comment: @Integrand It provides an answer to part A. It half provides an answer to part B because there are infinitely many configurations, but like I mentioned, I don't know if there are other configurations.

Comment: @Cesar A) I'm not certain what your comment is referring to (with regards to my solution). I'm not referencing your set up. B) Hexagon is a typo, I meant pentagon. It's just an example for the case without a perpendicular, which as I pointed out, isn't what the question asks for. I sometimes find it helpful to look at a relaxed conditions, to see if they can shed more light on the problem. C) To clarify, do you know where we can place E in accordance with the hint? There is no need for calculus, and the only/main fact that I use is that stated in the hint.

Comment: @Calvin The diameters fix 4 points. You cannot place a fifth point at the center because you would get collinear points. The points cannot be collinear

Comment: @Cesar (and this is why it's important/helpful to state what you're thinking, because I'm no mind reader and certainly didn't know that's where you're thinking) A) I'm not saying to place E at the center. I agree that no 3 points are collinear B) Let me expand on the hint, because you're not getting it. "The angle subtended by a diameter is $90^\circ$." So, if $AB$ is a diameter, what is the locus of $E$ so that  lines $EA$ and $EB$ perpendicular to each other? Ditto for $EC$ and $ED$ perpendicular to each other?